# Bootstrap custom responsive classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Hi in my bootstrap page i want to make custom responsive styles, do i really always need to use the media tags like this?

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

in my magento shop i use a template called "galayomarket" which adds a class to the body tag depending on window width

```
<body class="adapt-3"> LARGE DESKTOP
<body class="adapt-2"> DESKTOP
<body class="adapt-1"> TABLET
<body class="adapt-0"> MOBILE
```

so i can style simply with these classes, for example i want to change the background color for a table on mobiles:

```
.adapt-0 table {
    backgorund-color: white;
}
```

instead of using the @media like this

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
    table { backgorund-color: white; }
}
```

is there something similar in bootstrap i missed? I can only find the classes to hide/show elements depending on screensize.

Comment: I think both the concept are same. In bootstrap you need to use media-query for different view-port.

Comment: yes but i have always to remeber or lookup the px-numbers, with the class i have a shortcut

Comment: For remembering you can make custom classes. Like for mobile view, you need a red background in a table, for eg: `mobile-tablebg-red`. But media-query is simple brother, you can easily remember after 2, 3 times work.